# TexturePacker2 cuts filenames (not only suffix)

Tags: libgdx

I am using TexturePacker2 to create a TextureAtlas for libGDX. My filenames are put together by a name, a daytime and a x- and y-position.

```
mytexture_atday_300_400.png
```

In the myPackage.pack file every TextureRegion occur like this:

```
mytexture_atday_300
```

Even if I set the property 'useIndexes' for packing to true... no file suffix and a missing last part of the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TexturePacker` always trim the word after the last underscore, then used to be the name of `TextureRegion`. You should change your filename to use another separator, such as hyphen "-". I think there are no other way.

Comment: This is not possible because of internal naming conventions. I have to write a workaround for this. Thank you for the information that this is a normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If an image file name ENDS with underscore and then a number (eg animation_23.png), the number is considered the "index" and is stored separately. The image name is stored without the underscore and index. TextureAtlas allows a list of all images with the same name to be retrieved, ordered by index. This makes it easy to pack animations without losing the order of the frames.